# Paragraphs indentation with HTML Help Workshop

Tags: html, indentation, html-lists, paragraphs

I have a list of two indented paragraphs in a HTML file. Here is my code:

```
<ol><li>
            <p style="width: 765px; text-align: justify;">
                el método clásico basado en el concepto de equinoccio.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
            <p style="text-align: justify; width: 765px;">
                el método basado en el Origen Celeste Intermedio (OCI, CIO en siglas inglesas, 
                punto que corresponde al origen de ascensiones rectas en el sistema CIRS que se define más adelante), 
                siendo este último el adoptado por SIMORBI.</p></li>
                </ol>
```

This HTML file is part of a project to create a help with HTML Help Workshop (HHW). My browser shows it correctly but the resulting help (file .chm) of HHW shows

[image]

I do not understand why the number 2 is not at the same level (line) that the beginning of second paragraph and I would like to know how I could to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as it is shouldn't produce the result shown above. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/n9QBd/

You must be having other styles on your page applying that effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have edited my question to add more information about my problem.